# Jquery or Javascript to count chars and if not equal to 20 in two fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for away to have a script count the characters in 2 text areas and if it does not equal to 20 chars it adds "whitespace" to 20.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Go try to figure out how to do it on your own. If you get stuck on something specific, come back here, show what you have so far, and describe in clear detail what you're not understanding.

Comment: @amnotiam. You're right. Just wanted to see how much time it would take me to implement this + fiddle + write an answer (< 2 mintues) **Lazy**

Comment: @gdoron: I completely understand. In a way there can be lots of benefit to people like you who are not afraid of a challenge, and see it as an exercise at minimum, and potentially an opportunity to learn something along the way. That's commendable. Sadly, your type of person seems to be a rare breed. StackOverflow feels more and more to me like a welfare program.

Comment: @amnotiam. _"welfare program"_. **lol!!!**. any way, it's the same thing across the whole internet, not SO specific. A penalty\banned for "what have you tried" kind of questions might prevent this welfare behavior, You can suggest it in meta, I'll upvote it (as many others)!

Answer (score 4):

```
var combined = $('#first').val() + $('#second').val();

while (combined.length < 20) 
{
    combined += ' ';
}

alert(combined);
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/URSEs/)

Comment: I like this one better. Nice example.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the text in the textarea and keep padding it until it is 20 in length.

**HTML**:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<a id="pad" href="#">Pad to 20</a>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("#pad").click(function(){
$("textarea").each(function(index, element){
    while(this.value.length < 20){
        this.value = this.value + " ";     
    }
});
```

});​

[**Try it out!**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/q2wbz/)

Comment: You could spare the `$(element type).val` stuff, and just write `this.value` it will make your code a lot more readable and a bit more efficient. By the way, the fiddle shows nothing... =)

Comment: @gdoron Good point. I fixed it. I also changed the jsfiddle to demo it better. Thanks!

Comment: Now I can upvote it! though I understand from the question he wantw to combine the two `<textarea>`s before the padding.

Answer (score 0):

This would take an input string and create a 20-char min string from it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pad_right(s){
        if(s.length < 20){
            for (var i = 0; i < 20 - s.length; i++) {
                s += " ";
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function padString (text, length) {
    while (text.length < length)
        text = text + ' ';
    return text;
}
```